# Executing some code only when calling from unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, macros, windows-phone-7

I am developing one Windows phone 7 application. It has another project for unit testing. Now in the main application I have one method that executes some code to navigate to another page. While unit testing I don't want that method to execute and just return in the first line. Right now how I am doing it is defining a symbol while unit testing.

```
#define EnableUnitTest


public static void Navigate(string page)
{

 #if EnableUnitTest
     return;
 #endif
  .....
  .....       

}
```

Is there a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say it but that seems like a very bad design. In a unit test you are testing some code which shouldn't be conditioned that way. A unit test should consist of three steps: Arrange, Act, Assert where you prepare the input, call the actual method and assert the results. It's in the arrange step that you should prepare the method under test.

Also I notice that this method is static. Static methods are difficult to unit test. It would be better to abstract the logic of this class into an interface or abstract base class which could be easily mocked/stubbed in a unit test to weaken the coupling between the different parts of your code.

Comment: I am not testing that method. The purpose of that method is only to navigate to a new page. So for brevity I keep it in a static helper class. If I allow this code to run it will try to navigate to a new page that will throw an exception while unit test, but will work properly otherwise.

Comment: @Tanmoy, then simply don't call this method in your unit test. That was my point. The Navigate method is static and the method you are testing relies on it. This is why you have problems. You could abstract this method.

Comment: the problem the method in my ViewModel calls that navigate method internally. Do you think I should implement an interface and inject that class and mock in fromy Unit test code?